# How to Created Stylized Grainy Cel Shading

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, shadows, npr

How can I accomplish this look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SHNsKjnAgs) in this video, including changing the color of cast shadows and adding a gradient noise texture?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SHNsKjnAgs

[image]

Comment: Please include a screen shot or excerpt of the video in question. That will avoid having to watch a 20mn video and help you get an answer more quickly. thx

Comment: @Bruno Sorry about that here's a pic of what I'm wanting to go for. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shader to RGB node

Start by creating a bump map from a 3D noise like the following:

[image]

Feed a shader with strong specularity with the bump map. Then use the shader to rgb node to extract the color info of the surface. Use a color ramp node to tint the shadow, the midtones and the highlites.

[image]